# Chartkick on Heroku ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Chartkick?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-5, chartkick

I'm using chart kick in a standard way, like how the GitHub instructions dictate and it works in a local version. When uploaded to Heroku my charts produce an error "ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Chartkick" on the rendered partial page.

this is what I've done so far.

gemfile:

```
gem 'chartkick'
```

application.js:

```
//= require Chart.bundle
//= require chartkick
//= require_tree .
```

my show view renders a partial that calls a controller action via path method.

my controller action:

```
  def event_names
   @applet = RegisteredApplication.find(params[:id])
   render json: @applet.events.group(:name).count
  end
```

my partial that calls the action:

```
<%= pie_chart  event_names_registered_application_path  %>
```

I'm thinking the reason I'm getting the "ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Chartkick?" is because of the asset pipeline. But I don't fully understand what i can do to solve it is. please help :D

Comment: Seems unlikely that the issue only occurs on heroku.
Is your chart displayed locally ?

Comment: yes it works fine locally

Answer (score 0):

Just ran into the same issue. Make sure that `application.js` gets loaded *before* the Chart in your view. [See details](https://github.com/ankane/chartkick#installation)